# method 'comaddins' of object '_application' failed while looking for the registered COMAddins

Tags: com, vb6, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

We have this simple piece Where in we are registering an Addin and trying to find the Addin by looping through the list of Addins. This is not consistently reproducible on all the machines and we started seeing this on a client machine. We don't see anything wrong with the code either. We didn't see much on any of the forums. Please help.

When the code hits the for loop we get this error. Runtime Error -2147310770(8002801d). method 'comaddins' of object '_application' failed.

For Each oAddin In oWordApp.COMAddIns

```
Sub Main()

Call RegisterAddin

Dim oWordApp As New Word.Application

Dim oAddin As Office.COMAddIn

**For Each oAddin In oWordApp.COMAddIns**
    If oAddin.DESCRIPTION = "TestingCom Addin" Then
        oAddin.Connect = True
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting another Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application variable to Word.Application, then use Microsoft.Office.Core.COMAddIn to get items in the _Application.COMAddIns collection.

Comment: Wherever I use COMAddin, it throws the same error and crashes. Same piece of code works on all the other machines. Could this be an environment issue? Could it be due to some registry entry or the DLL that has gone wrong? Please suggest.

Comment: I can see the items under WordApp.ComAddins in the watch window but in the debug window it gives the error..

Comment: On the immediate window if I do this ?oWordApp.COMAddIns.Count I get 'Automation Error.. Library not registered'. Any idea which library is it referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using the below link. Looks like the previous/latest version of Office was not uninstalled properly and was causing problems with Office 2007.

http://kb.palisade.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=528